# The privilege to participate in Meta is unnecessary

Tags: feature-request, meta, privileges

As we all know, the first privilege you earn here is to post here at Meta Stack Exchange. Now what makes this confusing is that the next privilege is to be able to post in Meta... which is also Meta Stack Exchange. This means you only need 1 rep to get a five rep privilege. What?

I suggest that this [privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) (the five rep privilege) gets removed only for Meta Stack Exchange as it is confusing and conflicting.

Comment: -1 for not supporting recursion. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is just a general page, which is the same for every site. I link to that page sometimes when answering. Just like the badges that  are visible but can't be earned on some sites, this page is just adding to the consistency.

Did you really ever had someone complain about this? I didn't. Changing this doesn't change anything.